# Multiple data source and schema creation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, datasource, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot. I finally managed to setup two data sources, but now I'm facing another issue.

1. with two data sources in place `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` seems to stop working in my spring boot application, only `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` do the job now
2. I can not manage to select the auto-creation strategy for each of the data sources. I would prefer to create the schema for data source one, and just use the created schema in second DB with data source two.

Any body have idea how to resolve any of these issues? Note I don't want to completely throw away the auto-config if possible. I don't even know yet, if hibernate is able to just initialize schema in one persistence unit.

application.properties

```html
spring.datasource-internal.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
spring.datasource-internal.username=sa
spring.datasource-internal.password=sa
spring.datasource-internal.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
spring.datasource-internal.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

spring.datasource-external.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testexternal
spring.datasource-external.username=sa
spring.datasource-external.password=sa
spring.datasource-external.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
spring.datasource-external.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

flyway.enabled=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

DBInternalConfig

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "cz.data.internal",
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "internalEntityManagerFactory",
            transactionManagerRef = "internalTransactionManager")
    public class DBConfigInternal {


        public static final String INTERNAL = "internal";

        @Bean(name = "internalDataSource")
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource-internal")
        public DataSource internalDataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "internalEntityManagerFactory")
        @Primary
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean internalEntityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder
                    .dataSource(internalDataSource())
                    .packages("cz.data.internal.entity")
                    .persistenceUnit(INTERNAL)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "internalTransactionManager")
        @Primary
        public PlatformTransactionManager internalTransactionManager() {
            JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(internalDataSource());
            jpaTransactionManager.setPersistenceUnitName(INTERNAL);
            return jpaTransactionManager;
        }
    }
```

DBExternalConfig

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            basePackages = "cz.data.external",
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "externalEntityManagerFactory",
            transactionManagerRef = "externalTransactionManager")
    public class DBConfigExternal {


        public static final String EXTERNAL = "external";

        @Bean(name = "externalDataSource")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource-external")
        public DataSource externalDataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "externalEntityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean externalEntityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder
                    .dataSource(externalDataSource())
                    .packages("cz.data.external.entity")
                    .persistenceUnit(EXTERNAL)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "externalTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager externalTransactionManager() {
            JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(externalDataSource());
            jpaTransactionManager.setPersistenceUnitName(EXTERNAL);
            return jpaTransactionManager;
        }
    }
```

M.W.

Comment: There's no reason why `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` should stop working purely because you have two DataSources. Spring Boot will simply auto-configure Hibernate to use whichever DataSource is `@Primary`. I would guess that you've added some additional configuration that's switched off the auto-configuration of Hibernate but it's impossible to tell as you haven't provided enough information to recreate the issues that you're trying to resolve.

Comment: I have added some code snippets. I'm not very clear about the two options at all, I hardly see where they are even set up, no to mention where exactly they are hooked to the code. Anyway more important for me is the second issue, how to make it datasource specific.

Comment: Check this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup

Comment: I'm aware of this documentation. I want to be able to use auto generation, anyway I don't see option to use different flyway scripts for different data sources. I want to be able to initialize both data sources independently.

Comment: maybe something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13625889/2944265 , need to check how Spring Boot likes that:-/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` has stopped working, not because you have two DataSources, but because your application's creating its own `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`s. This has the effect of disabling the auto-configuration of a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` so you now have to configure it yourself.

You can configure the two entity managers to have different schema generation behaviour like this (the first's doing update, the second's doing create):

```
@Bean(name = "externalEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean externalEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    return builder
            .dataSource(externalDataSource())
            .packages("cz.data.external.entity")
            .persistenceUnit(EXTERNAL)
            .properties(properties)
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "internalEntityManagerFactory")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean internalEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    return builder
            .dataSource(internalDataSource())
            .packages("cz.data.internal.entity")
            .persistenceUnit(INTERNAL)
            .properties(properties)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I have followed your advice. The application seems to be working, but strange thing is I'm not able to see the tables in hsqldb(in memory), shouldn't it be possible that I screwed also something with transactions. So the transaction is still opened and not commited yet?:(

Comment: I'm also getting lots of  `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.NOTIFICATION`

Comment: Seems the HSQLDB process is not available to other [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5080465/2944265)

Comment: Can you please add the XML based configuration

Comment: @Andy - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086749/spring-batch-unable-to-create-metadata-tables-on-postgres-and-load-actual-data ?